# How to (correctly) exclude read-only properties with FluentAssertions?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I'd like to do a deep object comparison with [FluentAssertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki)' awesome `ShouldBeEquivalent` method that excludes read-only properties. The following works:

```
x.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(y, opts => opts.Excluding(si => !si.PropertyInfo.CanWrite));
```

But `PropertyInfo` is marked obsolete with the warning "This property will be removed in a future version.  Use `SelectedMemberInfo` instead." That type contains contains `Name`, `MemberType`, and `DeclaringType` and that's all, so not nearly enough to make certain checks against properties. (Internally it looks like the instance is actually a `PropertySelectedMemberInfo`, which adds nothing more.)

So what is the recommended, non-obsolete way make these sorts of checks against properties? Is `SelectedMemberInfo` still a work in progress?

Comment: We should have checked SO more pro-actively, because now we removed this property and it misses an option to get access to the PropertyInfo. We will need to add that to 4.2 or 4.3.

Comment: Thanks! I probably should have logged it on GitHub at the time instead.